# Is passing specification object is overkill in Repository

Tags: domain-driven-design

**Is passing specification object is overkill in Repository**

I am asking this because, if we pass specification object in method like FindCustomersCreatedToday,

```
class CustomerRepository
{
     public List<Customer> FindCustomersCreatedToday(ISpecification ISCreatedToday)
     {
         List<Customer> customers= Load all customers from db;

         List<Customer> newList=new List<>();

         foreach(var customer in customers)
         {  
              if(ISCreatedToday.SatisfiedBy(customer)
              {
                  newList.Add(customer);
              }
         }
     }

}
```

I above implementation in most of the sites i saw that, they fetch all entities from database and loop over them and pass each of them in to specification, but i don't like the idea of loading all entities at once and then create a new filtered list.

Suppose if i have 10000 customers and only 10 passes this criteria.

Is that not over kill to pass specification ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is definitely an overkill if you expect a lot of customers. You can use information in the instance of your specification to generate appropriate SQL/HQL or ICreteria (assuming you use NHibernate).

```
public IList<Customer> FindCustomers(CreationDateRangeSpecification spec) {
    ICriteria c = _nhibernateSession.CreateCriteria(typeof(Customer));
    c.Add(Restrictions.Between("_creationDate", spec.Start, spec.End));
    return c.List<Customer>();
}
```

This code is bit less expressive than the one you posted but it still good at capturing some domain information in Specification.

One thing to keep in mind when you work with Specification is that it is a domain concept. It belongs to domain layer and should be free of data access technologies. Technicalities of getting the data are important they just not important in domain layer, they belong to data access layer. Things like `Expression<Func<Customer, bool>>` are to 'infrastructural' for domain code in my opinion. In addition, Linq-based specification tend to require domain objects to expose their data as properties which sometimes breaks their encapsulation. So the whole thing may turn into "Linq over [Anemic Model](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html)".

I highly recommend you to read [DDD book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215). It has a chapter dedicated to Specification pattern and all the tradeoffs that you are dealing with.

Comment: I think in specification , object has only one property. IsSatisfiedBy which returns boolean value. But in your case, it is not. Moreover if you are passing ISpecification as parameter, then how it knows it has Start and End property, because ISpecification is an interface, either you have to expose it which i don't think is good idea.

Comment: @kamal: IsSatisfiedBy is not required. It is nice to have, but may not be needed if you only use Specification for passing to repository. I updated the answer with code and some explanations.

Comment: Dmitry can you help me in this http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2009/01/16/ddd-the-generic-repository/, he told us that we should not have generic repository, but we should have FindUserByName in repository instead of  FindUsers(Ispecification specification). What is your opinion ?

Comment: @kamal: He is right in case it is as simple as just Name. Specification is definitely overkill in this case. But if you have something more complex, like the concept of 'PremiumCustomer' then you can consolidate this logic in Specification. So your repository will have both FindByName(String) and FindByCustomerLevel(LevelSpec). I also prefer to not have generic Specifications (for the same reasons you don't have generic repository). Just keep it simple and domain oriented, do not generalize to much.

Answer (score 2):

As Ayende pointed in his [N-layer app review](http://ayende.com/blog/34817/review-microsoft-n-layer-app-sample-part-ixndash-not-invented-here-is-fun), **LINQ is the specification technology** you should use if you need specification pattern. It has an advantage of being convertible to SQL or HQL or any other query language so specifications expressed as `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` can be executed on the datasource without having to download all the data.

Comment: Thanks alot. i got this link from your link. http://linqspecs.codeplex.com/. But Greg young specified that we should not pass specification directly in an method because it may break some domain rules http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2009/01/16/ddd-the-generic-repository/. I need your comment on that.

Comment: Can you help me in this http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2009/01/16/ddd-the-generic-repository/, he told us that we should not have generic repository, but we should have FindUserByName in repository instead of  FindUsers(Ispecification specification). Is there not function explosion in repository.

Comment: There are two kinds of 'finder' methods. Usually, when trying to implement DDD without any sign of CQRS, both type of finder methods end up in repository objects. First one is used when processing transactions. It's usually GetSomethingById(id). It may be GetSomethingByName(name) or anything. The point is, this method is used by business logic. I agree with Greg that you should strive to be as explicit as possible here and not use specification.

Comment: Another kind of 'finder' methods are methods used by UI to show grid or detail views. They tend to have all sorts of different search criteria. I would encourage using specification or similar technique here, because there is no point in adding another 20 overloads of Find. Another important fact is that these finders tend to be very much dependent on UI, not on the domain model so it would not be a bad idea to place them in separate ISomethingFinder interface directly in the UI project. I will publish a blog post on that next Tuesday. Stay tuned:)

Comment: Please tell me where do i find the link , when you publish in blog ? I am eagerly waiting for it. Thanks Szymon for your cooperation, I am still a learner